# Angularjs UI Router states and $scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui-router.I'm having trouble with the search form submission. I seem to have the navigation working between states(home and then click on search button) and it takes you to the search results page BUT, no search is performed while autocomplete work..  I also noticed that the search terms are no longer in the search box when it goes to the results page.  With search terms not carrying over to the results page, I'm starting to think I have a $scope issue and I'm not sure why...?

My routes(states) are configured like this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');//default route for urls that don't have a specific route


$stateProvider

.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '': {templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'},//relatively named
      'navbar@home': {templateUrl: 'templates/navbar-home.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
      'autocomplete@home': {templateUrl: 'templates/autocomplete.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'}
    }
  })

.state('search', {
  url: '/search?searchTerms',
  views: {
    '': {templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'},//parent view, relatively named
    'navbar@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
    'searchDisplay@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/results.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
    'pagination@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/pagination.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'}
  }
})
```

Is the way I have my states and templates structured interfering with $scope? Is there a different way to set up my states and templates and have $scope working in the expected way?

NOTE: I'm using ui-sref on an `<a>` instead of a `<button>` for the "search button" - could that have anything to do with it? I'm using ui-sref because it seems better than using a `<button>` with ng-submit and state.go() in the function call in the controller.

Comment: Have you closed the `]` bracket eventually?

Comment: @SatejS yes its closed